# react typescript return value with asynchronous functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, async-await, axios

I don't understand what's wrong here.
I get the message: TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

I have a promise and I give number-type returns everywhere.

Does somebody has any idea?

```
export async function setAdress(newAdress: IAdress):Promise<number> {

 try {
    await axios.post<IAddAdressResult>('http://localhost:8090/rest/web/api/addAdress', newAdress)
        .then(res=> {
            if (res.data && (res.data as IAddAdressResult)) {
                alert('Address written successfully. ' + res.data.ADRESSID.toString());
                return res.data.ADRESSID
            } else return 0
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('Error writing the address ' + error);
            return 0

        });

 } catch (e) {
     return 0
 }
```

}

Comment: You don't return anything, or even assign the awaited value to be returned. Don't mix async/await and .try/.catch syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the whole Promise chain. As is, the `setAdress` function doesn't return anything.

You should also consider fixing the spelling to `address` (typos are a frequent source of bugs in programming), and the `try/catch` is superfluous if you also have a `.catch`.

```
export async function setAdress(newAdress: IAdress): Promise<number> {
    return axios.post<IAddAdressResult>('http://localhost:8090/rest/web/api/addAdress', newAdress)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data && (res.data as IAddAdressResult)) {
                alert('Address written successfully. ' + res.data.ADRESSID.toString());
                return res.data.ADRESSID
            } else return 0
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('Error writing the address ' + error);
            return 0

        });
}
```